# Openldap: How to restrict the audit log to track only user lockout, unlock and disable features

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have enabled the audit log for Open LDAP for the our system.
However, the log is showing all access details.
For eg; a positive login is having the below entry.

```
changetype: modify
replace: authTimestamp
authTimestamp: 20150915171011Z
```

I need to restrict the audit log for only when user account is unlocked or new user account is added or an existing account is deleted.

Tracking every access details will make the log file very big too.

Is it possible to restrict the audit log to track only certain attribute changes?

For eg: a failure attempt has the below entry

```
   changetype: modify
   add: pwdFailureTime
   pwdFailureTime: 20150915170706Z
```

I need to track only those attributes which are failed like above.

My slapd.conf file has the below entry.

```
#
# Audit information
#
overlay auditlog
auditlog /tmp/auditlog.ldif
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, as the merest glance at the [auditlog documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapo-auditlog) shows.

What you may be looking for is the [accesslog overlay](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapo-accesslog). It is at least configurable. More probably you should be adding the logging you need into your application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the suggestion of accesslog.